# inserting strings into linked list is not working correctly

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a program that is supposed to take an input file and extract the strings from it and add it to a linked list. I do not think I am adding the strings to the linked list correctly and i cannot seem to find the right way to. When the program executes it goes into an infinite loop for some reason.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct list {
    char *string;
    struct list *next;
};

typedef struct list LIST;

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char line[128];
    char file_name[20];
    LIST *current, *head;
    char *p, *s;

    head = current = NULL;
    printf ("Enter the name of the file: ");
    scanf("%s",file_name);

    fp = fopen(file_name, "r");

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
    {
        p = s = line;
        while(*p!=0)
        {
            if (*p==' ')
            {
                LIST *node = malloc(sizeof(LIST));
                *p = 0;
                 node->string = strdup(s);
                 node->next =NULL;

                if(head == NULL){
                current = head = node;
                } else {
                current = current->next = node;
                }
                s = p+1;
            }

            p++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    //test print
    for(current = head; current ; current=current->next){
        printf("   %s", current->string);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using the same node for all words in a line, thereby creating a loop where `node->next` equals `node`. You should create a new node when you insert a new word, not when you read a new line.

Comment: What do you learn when running in a debugger line by line?

Comment: @MOehm thanks. I changed the code above so that a new node is created when i insert a word. That fixed the infinite loop problem. It now prints out all of the words in the text file except the last one. Do you know why it doesn't save the last word in the file to the linked list?

Comment: Okay, now you have edited your code and corrected the problem. The question is now pointless. (You still need to catch the last word in the line; to do this, check for the newline `'\n'` in addition to the space or use `isspace` from `<ctype.h>`. You might also want to prevent the program from adding empty words to the list.)

Comment: @M Oehm the program already does not add empty words. It just skips the last word in the text file. How would I check for the newline?

Comment: It adds empty words if there are consecutive spaces in the input. Check for newline: `if (*p == ' ' || *p == '\n')`

Comment: Also, as I have already said, please don't fix your code in the question. It renders commenst and answers obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

- You are using the same node for all words in a line, thereby creating a loop where `node->next` equals `node`. You should create a new node when you insert a new word, not when you read a new line.
- You don't catch the last word of a line. You can make use of the fact that `fgets` retains the trailing new-line character and check for that in addition to checking for a space. You could also consider using `isspace` from `<ctype.h>`.

  Alternatively, and maybe better, is to defer the check for the null terminator until after the loop. You must then add a new word when you read a space or a null character.
- You insert empty words when the input file contains consecutive spaces or space characters. Your program should check whether `p > s` to add only valid words. (Or your program shoul only add valid words when the previously read character wasn't a space.)
- You allocate memory for the nodes and the strings. You should `free` this memory before exiting the program.

Here's your main loop with the fixes described above:

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
{
    char *p = line;
    char *s = line;

    do {
        if (*p== ' ' || *p == '\n' || *p == '\t' || *p == '\0') {
            if (p > s) {
                LIST *node = malloc(sizeof(LIST));

                *p = 0;
                node->string = strdup(s);
                node->next = NULL;

                if(head == NULL){
                    head = node;
                } else {
                    current->next = node;
                }
                current = node;
            }
            s = p + 1;
        }

        p++;
    }
    while (*p != 0);
}
```

Comment: ok thanks so much this helped out a lot. In one of my input files though it still did skip the last word.